# Monitor of my MSI A6200 laptop shows balck screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a MSI A6200 laptop which usually connected to a TV so I can watch the videos on both screens. Since the speed is very slow, I unstalled a lot of software from control panel.

Afterwards, the monitor on the laptop shows black but the TV screen is still OK. I opened the control panel to reset the display, but the box only shows one monitor instead of 1 & 2 as before.

I do not know what I deleted that may have caused this problem. I tried to reintall the driver from online software, but it needs a licence key which I don't have.

Comment: It's very odd that you would need a license key for a display driver. You are most likely looking in the wrong place. Identify the kind of video processor your laptop uses and search for a driver direct from the manufacturers website.

Comment: I will try to search for a driver from the manufaxrues website!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you uninstalled your display driver, or a component of it.

Here is a link to download the [display driver for Windows 7 64-bit from MSI](http://dl.msi.com/download_files/nb/dvr_exe/vga/vga_gmahd_8.15.10.2253_7v64.zip) (no license key required).

Comment: I will try to download the display driver from attached the link!Thank you very much!